# Sometimes my app starts from image of previously opened screen instead of splash screen

Tags: swift, ios13

Sometimes my app starts not from splash screen, but from image of last opened screen. It happens only on iOS 13. Problem is that there is a pin code screen in my app and user shouldn't see anything until pin code successfully passed.

Is this new feature of iOS 13? Or some "fun" feature from xcode or something? Can I disable it? Legitimately confused what's that all about...

Comment: it does the same in previous iOS versions too, I am currently working on a similar app with a passcode and as the app is about to enter background, i present a splash screen and then remove it when the app foregrounds.

Comment: You most probably confuse "cold-starting" the app and opening it from memory. If the user previously opened the app, iOS keeps it in memory until it runs out of free memory and when the user opens it again from memory, the system restore the previous state of the app. The app only starts with the splash screen if it was started from the disk, not from memory.

Comment: Thank you fellas! Tbh never noticed this behaviour before and was super confused about it. Gonna propose Scriptable solution.

Comment: I've been working on the launch screen and found that I have to force close the app to then see the launch screen again; a new feature of the iOS 13 Simulator at least, so not sure if it will stay with the public release.